# where can I get dx100 package?

Tags: ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I'm a beginner in ROS and now what I focus on is how to build the connection between ROS PC and my robot-controller.In the tutorial of create_joint_position_streaming_interface_using_tcp_socket_libraries, the tutorial told me that

> The ROS Code to support this interface can be found in the dx100 package. This code can be reused for different controllers as it was developed genercially.

So I want to download the `dx100` package. But I found that I cannot downliad it although I have broken th GFW(proxy), I cannnot download the package from googlecode. This is the link `https://swri-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/branches/groovy/motoman`.

So can somebody tell me where can I download this package or send one to my mail?(mail:shantengfei@sjtu.edu.cn). Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268746/where-can-i-get-dx100-package?/) by [tengfei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31490/tengfei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2017-08-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `dx100` package doesn't exist any more. The functionality was merged into `industrial_core`, more specifically: [industrial_robot_client](http://wiki.ros.org/industrial_robot_client) and [simple_message](http://wiki.ros.org/simple_message).

> This is the link `https://swri-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/branches/groovy/motoman`.

And with the shutdown of Google code, this repository was also taken down. Just for reference: a copy of it can be found at [ros-industrial/swri-ros-pkg](https://github.com/ros-industrial/swri-ros-pkg). But please *do not* use the `dx100` package from there: it's old and replaced by other packages.

> what I focus on is how to build the connection between ROS PC and my robot-controller

`simple_message` and `industrial_robot_client` can definitely be used for that, but it might be worthwhile to discuss your approach a bit, as there may be easier / more straightforward approaches, especially if your robot controller supports something like C/C++ (or any other high-level language) already.

I would suggest sending a message to the [ROS-Industrial mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/swri-ros-pkg-dev).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tengfei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31490/tengfei/) on 2017-08-14**:
Thank you， gvdhoorn！my robot controller does support C/C++,but not manufactured by vendor.I just looked through the  ROS-Industrial mailing list and found some similar forum. So what I should do as you said is asking for some suggestions by sending a detailed description to the mailing list right?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-14**:
Yes. Please include all relevant information.

**Comment by [tengfei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31490/tengfei/) on 2017-08-14**:
Thank you！ gvdhoorn,sorry to bother you again.As you said,the dx100 package was too old.But I want to know the tutorials/create_joint_position_streaming_interface_using_tcp_socket_libraries still avaliable for me to build the server on robot controller?